# Как удалить тень под выпадающим списком QComboBox?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox

Весь вопрос уместился в заголовке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот таблица стилей:

```
 QComboBox {
    
    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);
 }

QComboBox:hover {
    border: 2px solid rgb(194, 194, 255);
}
QComboBox:focus {
    border: 2px solid rgb(140, 146, 255);
}

QComboBox::drop-down 
{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(212, 215, 255);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    selection-background-color: rgb(140, 146, 255);
    
}

QComboBox QListView{
outline: 0px;
}





/* ===================== QScrollBar ======================= */
QScrollBar:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(243, 244, 255);
    width: 10px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background-color: rgb(194, 194, 255);       
    min-height: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}


QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(./images/up_arrow_disabled.png);        
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px; 
    border-image: url(./images/up_arrow_disabled.png);      
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover,QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:on {
    border-image: url(./images/up_arrow.png);                 
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

 QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: В данной таблице стиля нет теней, ищите в другом месте box-shadow, отвечает за тень

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выпадающий список это модальное окно и тень ему добавляет оконный менеджер.

Значит никак средствами css это не исправить.

Нужно этому окну добавить хинт `Qt::NoDropShadowWindowHint` чтоб попросить ОС не добавлять тень.

В плюсах это делается через `comboBox->view()->window()->setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::NoDropShadowWindowHint );`  [ссылка](https://forum.qt.io/topic/73716/qcombobox-shadow-effect-of-drop-down-popup-removable/3)

В питоне это будет следующая строка (*из коммента*):

```
self.comboBox.view().window().setWindowFlags(
    Qt.Popup | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.NoDropShadowWindowHint
)
```

Comment: Спасибо, это решает мою проблему. В питоне это будет следующая строка: ```self.comboBox.view().window().setWindowFlags(Qt.Popup | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.NoDropShadowWindowHint) ```